# How to increase box size first by height then by width in case of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.box {
  background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  ab cd ef gh ij kl mn
</div>
```

In above code, we are using `min-height` and `min-width` as 50 and `max-height` and `max-width` as 100.

By default if I starting putting text, default behavior is that DIV box will increase size first at width level.i.e. first it will increase width fro 50 to 100 and then it will start increase height.

I would like to know if we can change the order. i.e. first by height and then by width.

i.e. first it should grow down from min-height to max-height. Once it reaches max height , it should start increase width wise.

Comment: Thanks for your comments...We did internal research..further checked with one of web designer company..but no one could give any solution ..hence i have posted it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because your browser is by default using the CSS property of writing-mode: horizontal-tb. Text fills the box from left to right and then top to bottom, the way we write words in most of the western world. If you change the CSS to be writing-mode: vertical-lr, the text will fill the box from top to bottom and then left to right. In that case you fill see the box go to its max-height and then begin increasing width until you hit the limit.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: Thanks for providing direction...I have checked this option.....I found that once we set writing-mode to vertical ...the text grows vertically....(which is supposed to happen as per documentation)....... In our case....we would like text to grow horizontally ......but div box should grow first vertically and then horizontally